# AngularJS and CanvasJS Bar Chart Index Labels - how to show them?

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I have a basic `CanvasJS` Chart inside and `AngularJS` controller that shows data from the $scope of that controller. I don't really know if this information is relevant, but maybe it will help you understand better the context of the creation of the bar chart.
Anyways, I want to add Index Labels to each bar, to show the value of each data point above each bar. I looked over the `CanvasJS` documentation and tried placing Index `Label: "{y}"` both inside the `dataset` object and inside the data array but nothing seems to work. The chart loads, but the Index Labels are not visible at all.
Here's my chart snippet below.

```js
ageChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("ageChart").getContext("2d")).Bar({
    labels: ['Critical', 'Major', 'Minor'],
    datasets: [{
                       fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                       strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                       highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                       highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                       data: [$scope.employeeData.data1, $scope.employeeData.data2, $scope.employeeData.data3]
    }]
      }, {showScale: false, responsive: true, barValueSpacing: 25});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snipped for showing CanvasJS Bar Chart Index Labels using AngularJS.

```js
var myapp = angular.module("myapp", []);

myapp.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope",function($scope){
  $scope.data = [{
                  x: 1,
                  y: 10,
                  indexLabel:"{y}"
                },
                {
                  x: 2,
                  y: 20,
                  indexLabel:"{y}"
                },
                {
                  x: 3,
                  y: 30,
                  indexLabel:"{y}"
                },
                {
                  x: 4,
                  y: 20,
                  indexLabel:"{y}"
                },
                {
                  x: 5,
                  y: 10,
                  indexLabel:"{y}"
                }];
  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    data: [{
      type: "bar",
      dataPoints: $scope.data
    }]
  });
  chart.render();
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 320px; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Would you happen to know why i am getting `CanvasJS` as a `cannot find name` error?

Comment: You was getting the error as Browser was blocking canvasjs.min.js file requested through http protocol. I have edited the snipped to load the file with https request.